# Web project log files doesn't have dll log entries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, log4net

We have an internal class library project that is used across multiple web applications. The web projects are consuming this class library as dll. On localhost, the class library's log are written to web projects log file. But i don't see this is happening on servers. I don't see dll's log entries are being written to web project log file. PS: we are using log4net for logging.

Any insight on this please?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment, so I am posting an answer even if I will not give you a solution.
I would check the log4net configuration on the web application(s) which are using your library. Maybe the log messages are filtered. More information on this: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html. Check the **Loggers** and **Filters** sections.

Comment: I checked the filter section, they are not filtered out. Another strange thing is it logs the log entries from dll in test server/localhost but not in production server. I compared the web.config between the servers. The log4net setttings are same between the servers. I am not sure what else to check.

Comment: Then I have some more questions: 1) do the consumer web application(s) too rely on log4net for logging “themselves” or 2) they rely on some other logging mechanism, and it is your library only which requires log4net to log? I mean, at this point I am starting to suspect that a) IIS in production does not have the privileges to write to the path where you are expecting log4net to write. Or, b) that the consumer web application(s) are not injecting any logger into your library (because they are not bootstrapping any log4net logger).

Comment: Answers to your question, 1) Yes, the web application(s) are internal too and yes it is also using log4net for logging. 2) class library is also internal application which is using log4net. a) On production/test server, the log files are created and writing the web project's logs to it, the application user on IIS has admin access. On test, the complete logging is being written, web and class library logs but on production, it just has web project's logs and library logs are not written to it. Not sure what else to look for.

Comment: Any other suggestions on this from expertise please?

Comment: No idea. Try stopping IIS, redeploying and restarting IIS.